# NodeJS - variable is undefined due to a circular dependency?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using `yargs`. The variable `argv` seems to be undefined (see `logger.ts`), though I do know it does exists, and got parsed just fine (`console.log` in `parseArgs.ts`). I suspect it is because of a circular dependency `fetchRange` -> `logger` -> `parseArgs` -> `fetchRange`.

Am I correct? If so, does it mean that if a function uses commandline args, I cannot reference it within the yargs config whatsoever?

```js
// logger.ts
import winston from "winston";
import { argv } from "./parseArgs";

export const logger = winston.createLogger({
  level: argv.verbosity, // this is undefined!
});
```

```js
// parseArgs.ts
import yargs from "yargs";
import { fetchRange } from "./fetchRange";

export const argv = yargs
    .command(
        /* Some unimportant stuff */
        argv => {
            fetchRange(strToDate(argv.fromDate), strToDate(argv.toDate));
        }
    ).argv;
console.log(argv) // This is NOT undefined!
```

```js
// fetchRange.ts
import { logger } from "./logger";

export const fetchRange = async (fromDate: Date, toDate: Date) => {
  /* Some unimportant stuff */
    logger.verbose(`Day ${dateToStr(i)} finished.`);

};
```

Comment: Simple fix to circular dependency is to just make stuff a function `export const argv = () => yargs.command(...`. And then you can do `argv().verbosity` in `logger`

Comment: Most likely, avoid circular dependencies if you can.  An easy way for you to do this is create another unit, maybe called common and export an object that you can store your argv on.  In typescript I often use this for also storing interfaces etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I suspect it is because of a circular dependency `fetchRange` -> `logger` -> `parseArgs` -> `fetchRange`

Yes, that's correct. `parseArgs` is importing `fetchRange` which is importing `logger`, and that module does access `argv.verbosity` *before* the `yargs.command(…)` call is executed that initialises `argv`.

At least that happens when `parseArgs` is imported first. When `fetchRange` is imported first, it does work (but then `fetchRange` will be uninitialised inside `parseArgs`, which doesn't matter however as it is not used immediately).

So you can either keep the circular dependency, and tightly control what module to use as an entry point into the circle. Or you use dependency inversion, remove the `argv` import into `logger`, and instead configure the verbosity level on an already existing logger instance after having parsed the command line arguments.

Comment: Why isn't there some kind of an inifinite loop created while initializing? What exactly does happen during module initialization? Where can i gather in-depth knowledge about it? What keywords to search for?

Comment: @JohnSmith The infinite loop ends when the engine attempts to load a module that it already had loaded - even if it hasn't finished (or even started) evaluating it. You just get back aliases to the uninitialised variables.

Comment: @JohnSmith Sorry I don't know any good resource for this. There's a few SO questions about the topic, but none in-depth, and I still haven't gotten around writing a canonical reference for it.